# Two positions of the convex lens for a fixed object-screen separation

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses

Explain why, for a fixed separation between the object and the screen(i.e., d + d' is fixed) there are two positions of the lens at which the images formed on the screen are in focus (clear images or sharp images). Please provide me with a proof with diagrams, I am unable to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the following [figure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R_0Cf3u46I_59qCXqHj-huXC_eWqDiUf)where the screen is at $x=0$,the object at $x=a$ and the convex lense(with focus $f$) is at variable point $x=b$. Then for sharpe image on the screen we have :
 $$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{v}-\frac{1}{u}$$
$$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{b-a}$$
$$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{b-a-b}{(b-a)(b)}$$
$$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{-a}{b(b-a)}$$
$$b^2-ab+af=0$$
It is quadratic equation with two real roots iff
$$a^2-4af\geq0$$or$$a\geq4f$$.